# Possible customer asking to do a favor of paying the ex owner of house he bought

Tags: scams

I got a possible customer and everything was going good. He wanted to pay upfront, but send by mail and then we do the work after we cash the check.
Later he asks if we can do him a favor - that he will send a check with extra commission fee that he has to pay to the ex owner of a house he bought.

I think he is trying to scam me because who sends a 2500 check and wants you to deposit to someone who you don't even have anything to do with? He's the one who would be doing that payment, not me.
He wants me to just take my part out which is 300, which makes no sense.

Please give me an opinion. I've never had anyone ask this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why, in case of a check scam, am I the responsible one and not the bank?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/107159/why-in-case-of-a-check-scam-am-i-the-responsible-one-and-not-the-bank)

Comment: Yes, this is fraud. Never become a payment 'intermediary', which is typically a way that scammers insert you into a series of transactions to commit money laundering, or else simply to steal money from you. It could be some days or even weeks after your cheque 'clears' that the bank realizes the funds were not available from the original sender, and at the end of it all, you will have sent money to someone else, and gotten nothing in return.

Comment: Thanks so much i really appreciate the help!

Comment: I think this deserves an answer, unless there is an actual duplicate that explains that every time someone asks you to forward money it's a scam.

Comment: Thanks im glad i didnt agree to any thing that guy said. Before it was too late

Comment: https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scams

Answer (score 8):

The check will bounce.  It's probably stolen or forged.  By the time you are told that it has bounced, you will already have sent 2200 of the 2500 to somebody else.  So you will end up 2200 out of pocket.

Comment: Actually, he'll be $2500 out of pocket.  In addition to sending $2200 to a 3rd party, he's done work to the value of $300 and received no real payment for it.

Answer (score 3):

The other sign of the scam is that you're doing some sort of work. I don't know what that is, contracting, art, selling squirrel tails, whatever...

None of that work is banking or money transfers is it?

If I want to move money around, I go to a place that exists to help me move money around. A bank, Venmo, PayPal, Zelle, Western Union, etc. You are not a bank so it's a sure sign of a scam when someone asks you to do banking work and not your actual job.